SOT23 marking code identification "OAR7DN"
Please assist in identifying marking code for device type SOT-23 SMD


Please refer to the component identification guidelines. To get such questions answered effectively, you need to provide details about what device the part was found in, a rough idea of what it might be used for if known, and ideally a photo of the surrounding circuity.

This question is similar to: Marking code help. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's a LA431OCRPA voltage reference, manufactured by Lite-On or Diodes Inc. The following pictures are from the Lite-On version, but the diodes one looks similar.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Hi, thank you kindly, your information is greatly appreciated and of great assistance
